# Suddenly disconnected from my wireless network. Can't reconnect

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have Windows 7 on a laptop with an Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced N+ WiMax 6250 card. Last night, I was browsing the internet when suddenly I couldn't connect to a site. I looked down and my network status was changed. It now said "Currently connected to Unidentified Network. No internet access." I'm not able to see any networks to connect to, but all the other computers in our house are working.

I then tried restarting but it didn't work. I suspected I had a virus because of some other strange things it's been doing. I did a scan and it found a trojan.Generic3_c.AUYS in Appdata\Local\Temp\upnp.exe. I removed it but I still can't connect.

In Device Manager, it has a warning symbol on my network card. I disabled and re-enabled it to no avail. I also ran ipconfig /all, and it says "Media Disconnected" on everything. The only recent thing I did was install some themes. I can't imagine how that would affect anything.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your router via wire?  Are other devices on the router working?  Have you tried restarting the router?  Have you connected to the router to check its status?

Comment: The warning symbol in Device Manager suggests something is wrong with the wireless card.  What does double-clicking on it show in the properties dialog?  Did you try removing and re-installing the card?

Comment: (And is your "radio" perhaps turned off?  Some laptops have a physical switch that's easy to bump accidentally, others use a function key.)

Comment: Try a System Restore back to a point when it was working as expected (say Friday morning).  Try Safe Mode with Networking.  Look in the Event Logs for possibly-related errors. Try a fresh OS install. Try a new network adapter.

Answer (score 1):

A few troubleshooting ideas:

- Make sure other *wireless* devices on your network are working to rule out a router issue. Assuming they work, then we know the issue is limited to your laptop.
- Boot into Safe Mode with Networking. This will enable networking but should prevent any malware from starting and/or affecting your network connection. If this works, you are likely correct that there is some malware on your machine. Run scans/removal tools in Safe Mode to try to clean them up.
- Once you run scan and removal software, try to reinstall your network drivers from your manufacturer.

Let me know how these work and we can keep going from there.